# Animate Activity transition: nothing happens

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

Hi and thanks for your help.

I want to animate the transition between two activities, but so far without success...

Activity A launches activity B via strartActivity();

In onCreate() of activity B I put the following code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in,R.anim.out);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

---

EDIT EDIT:

After suggestions I changed removed the above code and added in the Activity A (that starts Activity B)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public DataBaseHelper db;
public EditText enter;
public TextView tv;
public ArrayList<String> listWord;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try {
        db.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        db.openDataBase();
        Log.e("", "database aperto");
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    Cursor constantsCursor = db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT _id, korean FROM data ", null);

    enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    bn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

        }
    });

}
```

**Again no animation happens...**

I would expect an animation to happen when the Activity B starts, but nothing happens

Thre are my R.anim.in and R.anim.out.

**R.anim.in**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:zAdjustment="top" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="-45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="0"
         />

</set>
```

**R.anim.out**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-45"
        />

</set>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Activity` A, where you launch `Activity` B, you have to call `overridePendingTransition` after `startActivity` call.

Code in `Activity` A -

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtras(...);
i.setFlags(...);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
```

Comment: Check if Android settings is correct in your device. Do other apps show animation?

Comment: that was it! Please post an answer! I will accept it, upvote it, and send you 100 bucks as well !!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

call overridePendingTransition **after** calling startActivity:

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(...)
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int) : _Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or finish() to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next._

Comment: use android std animations from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim.html e.g. fade*, slide° and see if they work. if so that it means your custom animations are broken

Comment: @pskink Thank you. Indeed I tried. with overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right) NO SUCCCESS....